# root of equation using bisection method

Tags: roots

We have the equation $f(x)=x^3-7x^2 + 14x -6 $ .I have to find the root of the equation using bisection method in the interval of  $]1.3 , 2 [$

First I find $f(1.3)=2.567 >0 $ and $f(2)=2>0$

I guess this means that based on the Intermediate Value Theorem the function isn't continuous and there isnt a $p∈]1.3 , 2[$ such that $f(p)=0$?

Anyway $a0=1.3$ and $b0=2$ ..we have $p0=a0+ [(b0-a0)/2]=1.65$ ...And we have $f(po)=2.53$,which is  positive,same as $f(a0)$ and $f(b0)$.

This means$ a1=po=1.65$,$b1=bo=2$...and I should go on with the iterations,but I dont understand,for how long should I go on?

Comment: Are you sure that a root exists in the given interval ? Remember that the function is continuous.

Comment: Thats what I have written,since f(1.3)=2.567>0 and f(2)=2>0 ,this means that the function isnt continuous in the given interval,therefore we dont have a p∈ ]1.3 ,2[ such that f(p)=0

Comment: The function is a polynomial so it is continuous, even more it's differentiable..

Comment: To answer partly the question *for how long should I go on ?*, I would answer *don't start*. You cannot start bisection if the interval does not contain the root.

Comment: If the function does not change sign at the end points it does NOT mean that the function is not continuous.

Comment: I understand.How do I prove that a root doesnt exist in the given interval?

Comment: In this case by luck we have the root $3$, so we can find nice expressions for all the roots.